# How to report "invalid" portals?

Tags: ingress

I looked through the ingress help, but could not find this information. I know I can report bad title/bad description/bad position from the portal info screen.

But how can I report invalid portals? For example:

- inaccessible portals (e.g. on private property)
- duplicate portals (e.g. 3 portals on the same sculpture, mostly overlapping)
- for no longer existing temporary art installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that here:

General Niantic "Contact us":
https://support.google.com/ingress/#contact=1

Report an issue with a portal:
https://support.google.com/ingress/#contact=1&ts=2848642

The options you asked for are only available there, not in the mobile app (yet).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this from the mobile client.

Use the web:

https://support.google.com/ingress